# Poco Poco::NotificationQueue not working as expected

Tags: c++, multithreading, notifications, poco

I'm starting using `Poco::NotificationQueue`. I have noticed that strange behavior, if more than one worker-threads are waiting on the same `NotificationQueue` using `waitDequeueNotification()`, only one of the tread receives a notification sent from a master-thread.
This is obvious if you run the NotificationQueue.cpp example provided with Poco (in this case done from Visual Studio, but the result is the same when tested on Linux).

The output from it is :

> ```
> Worker 1 got work notification 0
> Worker 3 got work notification 2
> Worker 2 got work notification 1
> Worker 1 got work notification 3
> Worker 3 got work notification 4
> Worker 2 got work notification 5
> ...
> ```

Expected result would be:

> ```
> Worker 1 got work notification 0
> Worker 3 got work notification 0
> Worker 2 got work notification 0
> Worker 1 got work notification 1
> Worker 3 got work notification 1
> Worker 2 got work notification 1
> .....
> ```

Is this a bug or what? If so is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug, but your expectations are wrong.

The `NotificationQueue` is designed to notify the `Worker` threads about jobs to do. each `Notification` represents a job to complete. If `Worker` 1 is already working on the task, why should the next free `Worker` start working on the same task? The whole use of multithreading is parallelization of work. So multiple jobs can be processed ad the same time.

If you want each Thread to receive the same `Notification`, you should **not** use a `NotificationQueue`. Instead you should use a [`NotificationCenter`](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.NotificationCenter.html) with `Observers`.

See these slides for more information: [NotificationsEvents.pdf](http://pocoproject.org/slides/090-NotificationsEvents.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's design intend. You are obtaining new notification invoking `waitDequeueNotification()` or `dequeueNotification()`. Both functions get notification and do remove it from the appropriate queue.

If you wish to notify every working thread, you need to send notification for each thread separately (every working thread should have own queue).